# Swift: enum names with special characters (like .) in them

Tags: swift, enums, lexical

how can I create an enum with "." or "-" in their names? I want something like:

```
 enum Options: String {
     case option1, option2, option2.1, option3
 }
```

Using backticks (``) doesn't work. Is there some work-around I can do?

Comment: You can't so use _ or some other approved character. Back ticks are to be used when you want an identifier name to be the same as a reserved word in swift like class or case or enum

Comment: @JoakimDanielson you mean "you can"

Comment: @LeoDabus, maybe a misunderstanding. My "can't" refers to the first sentence in the question and not the last. If that's not it then please explain how I am wrong.

Comment: sorry I missed the "so" word there. A punctuation there would help reading it correctly

Answer (score 1):

Neither character can be part of an identifier name. See https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/LexicalStructure.html for the grammar.

Answer (score 1):

Like Gereon says, basically, you can't. It is a very archaic system. But if you can find a good emoji you like, that'll work.

```swift
enum Option: String {
  case option1, option2, option21, option3
}
```

Also, note that each one is an *Option*, not an *Options*.

Comment: IMO it would be better to use something like option2a

Comment: I hate underscores, but I still use a lot of them because I think they’re the best substitute for periods. e.g. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlfeatureset